# Javascript - how to check "certain" checkboxes and not all using my current code?

Tags: javascript

So I have two tables that pop open on one page. Here's the script that I've been previously using to select all of the checkboxes in the first table (which was the only one at the time):

```
<script>
  $('#selectAll').click(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
     $(':checkbox').each(function() {
       this.checked = true;                        
     });
   } else {
    $(':checkbox').each(function() {
     this.checked = false;                        
   });
  } 
});
</script>
```

How can I change this to be more specific? Do I need to add a specific class or ID attribute to the checkbox for this to work?

Comment: you're already using a selector, time to understand how they work! http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Cool. Now that I know how they work, how do I get mine to work the way I'm trying to get it to work? Also, I'm using the "name" attribute for various different things, so I would like to accomplish this without having to change the name for every checkbox.

Comment: this is not a "give me the correct code" site. What have you tried to far? What have you researched? What is the last code you tried it with?

Comment: I'm not asking you for the "exact code" necessarily. I'm just asking for more or less a better pointer for my specific situation, not a link explaining what I've already done. The scenarios that I'm running across are selecting specific checkboxes based on their "name" attributes, and I can't use this.

Comment: You could use [this](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to check them based on their name attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that both tables have class `.table`. Optimized version of your script which would work for both tables can look like this:

```
$('.table').on('click', '.selectAll', function(e) {
    $(':checkbox', e.delegateTarget).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Notes:

1. Instead of id `#selectAll` your select-all checkboxes must have **class** `.selectAll`.
2. With `.on` method we bind one click event handler to table, which triggers when `.selectAll` is clicked. `e.delegateTarget` points to the current table DOMElement. Then `$(':checkbox', e.delegateTarget)` means `find checkboxes within current table`.
3. Instead of looping with `each` method and setting `checked = true/false` you can use jQuery's `prop` method to do the same but more concise.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pkp7osfn/